# Why can't I use processing algorithms in a standalone PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I want to create a standalone python script using QGIS python API (PYQGIS) for education.
First I create a model and export that model to python script.

original python script from the export :

```
##=name
##raster=raster
##stat=output html
outputs_QGISRASTERLAYERSTATISTICS_1=processing.runalg('qgis:rasterlayerstatistics', raster,stat)
```

Next I read this [Using PyQGIS in standalone scripts](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts) and I tried to follow this tutorial to create my script.

Final script :

```
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('/home/username/.qgis2/python')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
dem='aster.tif'
slope='slope.tif'
aspect='aspect.tif'
outputs_SAGASLOPEASPECTCURVATURE_1=processing.runalg('saga:slopeaspectcurvature', dem,6,1,1,slope,aspect,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None)
Processing.initialize()

# Exit applications
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

If I run this script it works fine without error but I don't take some export like `aspect` and `slope` (these can't be found?). Any idea why I can't take exports ?

I use Ubuntu and python 2.7 and QGIS 2.18.1.

---

i try to this script :

```
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
import processing
a=processing.alglist()
print a
processing.alghelp("saga:slopeaspectcurvature")
```

and i take that print any idea why ?

```
Algorithm not found
```

but if i use this module in QGIS work fine.

Comment: Did you define the full path for all your export files? i.e. `aspect="path/to/aspect.tif"`?

Comment: yes i have define paths and no change,no exports

Comment: Perhaps your Processing is installed in `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins`, so you might need to use `sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins'`) instead.

Comment: not work again,work without error but i dont take exports,dont create the exports

Comment: maybe i need more commands to import raster layer in pyqgis ?