# Processing Model in a standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I have the same problem as in 
[Why can't I use processing algorithms in a standalone PyQGIS script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221032)

I know the question is not really up-to-date but does someone have an answer?

I've defined a Processing Model in QGIS 2.18 ('Las Palmas') and want to run it in a standalone PyQGIS-Script via command `processing.runalg('modeler:[...]')`. If I execute the script in the QGIS Python Console it works:

[image]

If I try to run the same code in a standalone script it fails with the message `'Algorithm not found'`.

Can somebody help?

Comment: There are various ways to draw attention to an old unanswered question but re-asking it is not one of them: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/options-when-question-is-duplicate-of-one-with-no-inadequate-old-answers