# Using QGIS models outside QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I use QGIS 2.14. I created a simple model using **processing --> grafic modeler**

In QGIS, I use python console and it works:

`processing.runalg("modeler:model_name","input","output")`

CanI running this model outside QGIS?

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259095/processing-model-in-a-standalone-pyqgis-scriptp

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @CiccioDiTrani! At the moment, it doesn't look like user-made scripts or models are exposed when running processing outside QGIS. You could consider posting a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis) and hope it will be implemented in a future version :)