# Exporting model to Python script using QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler, qgis-3

I want to edit a few things to my model in QGIS 3.2.2, but first I need to convert this model to Python script.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this feature has been removed until further enhancements are made. Please check the following links:

[Export model to Python script in QGIS 2.6?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121537/export-model-to-python-script-in-qgis-2-6/121727)

[Using qgis models outside qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260086/using-qgis-models-outside-qgis)

I do not see this feature in GIS 3.2.2

[image]

If it is urgent you could perhaps downgrade to QGIS 2.4 . Provided that the vesion can do the job you require.